# Install mongodb-org 3.4 on ubuntu 14.04: package 'mongodb-org' has no instlalation candidate

Tags: 14.04, mongodb

I'm trying to install `mongodb-org` using the instructions here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Here are the commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

But this results in the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb-org is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb-org' has no installation candidate
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `apt-cache` command to see what available `mongodb` packages are called: `apt-cache search mongodb`. No `sudo` is required for `apt-cache search`.

Comment: Thanks. apt-cache search mongodb has a lot of results, while apt-cache search mongodb-org does not return anything.

Comment: What's the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0):

This was User error. I had an entry in /etc/apt/preferences.d/50mongo. After removing that, the above commands worked without errors.